# Forming objects from a list to a new object

Tags: list, object

I have to create a train with locomotives and wagons. I created them and put them all in list, where I can give them an ID and sort them and such things.

My question is now if I can get some of them out of that list and form a new Object train with them, or is it better to just implement them directly without touching the list?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little vague, what type of data are these "locomotives" and "wagons"? How is that data going to be manipulated?

In general, if you have a complex possibly nested object it's better to create a Class for it. If you create a `Train` class, it can contain as an attribute a list of locomotives and wagons, which themselves are another Object. And better yet, you can define class specific functions to manipulate a Train's locomotives and wagons.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to make a constructor "variable" because different trains can contain different numbers of locomotives and wagons.

Comment: They are Objects from a class rail vehicle which extends them.

Comment: Yeah, you can set attribute to classes as needed. You can read about some OOP [here](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/)